# Change user profile's 'votes cast' icon

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page

A very minor 'bug' (in the sense that it slightly bothers me, not as in a glitch or mistake):

[image]

The icon in front of the total number of votes cast is the same as the one for upvotes.
Can this be turned into an icon with both an upward (▲) and downward pointing triangle (▼)?

I noticed it's a vector path, so I quickly wrote an alternative code, `<path d="M 10 1 l 4 4 h -8 m 0 2 h 8 l -4 4"></path>`, which gives:

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconArrowUpDown"  
width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path d="M 10 1 l 4 4 h -8 m 0 2 h 8 l -4 4"></path>
</svg>
```

As a user in the comments points out, this 'issue' was brought up years ago on Stack Overflow Meta, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306552/votes-cast-has-upvote-like-symbol-and-is-confusing), where two other solutions are given (of which one seems to have become obsolete).

Comment: I wonder why this is being downvoted, since this was [previously asked on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306552/votes-cast-has-upvote-like-symbol-and-is-confusing) and was heavily upvoted there. A then-employee marked it as under review in 2015, but nothing has happened since.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Probably by users who don't think this is in *any* way constructive: and I realize it's really low-priority - I get that aspect - but reckoned every little helps towards improved UX.

Comment: ⥮ `&#10606; &UpEquilibrium;` or ⇅ `&#8645; &UpArrowDownArrow;` or ⚒ `&#9874; hammer and pick` maybe two separate symbols: ␆␕ using ␆ `&#9222;symbol for acknowledge` and ␕ `&#9237; symbol for negative acknowledge`

Comment: I'd feel most for ⇅ UpArrowDownArrow @Rob.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The up triangle certainly sends a confusing message because the vote count includes both downvotes and upvotes. There is also no need for creating new icons, SE's own Stacks [design framework](https://stackoverflow.design/product/resources/icons/#arrowupdown) already has an up-and-down arrow icon to replace the current one with (see the [source repo](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Icons/blob/production/build/lib/Icon/ArrowUpDown.svg?short_path=0bccd6d)):

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconArrowUpDown" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
  <path d="m9 1 7 7H2l7-7zm0 16 7-7H2l7 7z"/>
</svg>
```

Here is how it looks like after replacing the original icon on the profile page:

[image: stats widget on the profile page]

Give it 6 to 8 weeks to be done. In the meantime, you can use this lightweight snippet to replace the icon:

```js
(() => {
    const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    const ICON_SEL = "div[title*='votes cast'] svg";

    const svg = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'svg');
    svg.classList.add('svg-icon', 'iconArrowUpDown');
    svg.setAttribute('width', '18');
    svg.setAttribute('height', '18');
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 18 18');
    svg.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');

    const path = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'path');
    path.setAttribute('d', 'm9 1 7 7H2l7-7zm0 16 7-7H2l7 7z');

    svg.append(path);

    const icon = document.querySelector(ICON_SEL);
    if (!icon) return;

    icon.replaceWith(svg);
})();
```

Transpiled to ES5 and minified version:

```js
"use strict";!function(){var t="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",e=document.createElementNS(t,"svg");e.classList.add("svg-icon","iconArrowUpDown"),e.setAttribute("width","18"),e.setAttribute("height","18"),e.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 18 18"),e.setAttribute("aria-hidden","true");t=document.createElementNS(t,"path");t.setAttribute("d","m9 1 7 7H2l7-7zm0 16 7-7H2l7 7z"),e.append(t);t=document.querySelector("div[title*='votes cast'] svg");t&&t.replaceWith(e)}();
```